# Is it possible to exclude an entrypoint from being split into chunks in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Given this in a webpack.config.js:

```
{
  entry: {
    a: '.../a.js',
    b: '.../b.js',
    separate: '.../separate.js',
    vendor: ['lib1', 'lib2', ...]
  },
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ["commons", "vendor"],
      minChunks: 2
    })
  ]
}
```

is it possible to have the `separate` entrypoint not be affected by common chunks? I would just like `separate.js` to be totally self contained and not list multiple assets in the manifest.json `entrypoints` listing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return multiple configs in `webpack.config.js` - this way you can reuse plugins, modules or whatever you have just don't add `commons` plugin to second config. Keep in mind that separate `webpack` runtimes will be generated - one in vendors to use in `a` and `b`, and second in `separate`.

```
return [
    {
        entry: {
            a: '.../a.js',
            b: '.../b.js',
            vendor: ['lib1', 'lib2', ...]
        },
        ...
        plugins: [
            ...
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                names: ["commons", "vendor"],
                minChunks: 2
            })
        ]
    },
    {
        ...
        entry: {
            separate: '.../separate.js'
        }
        ...
    }
];
```